# Handling user uploaded content in Capistrano

Tags: git, version-control, capistrano

I have setup capistrano for deployment to staging and production servers. The last thing bothering me is how to handle user uploaded content - at the moment, my uploads folder and its contents are versioned in my git repo. What I would like to do if possible and not bad practice, is to use the deployment script to do the usual deploy stuff, but also to push any new uploaded content on the prod server to the repo, by adding a task to the script.

Is this a sensible/possible move? How do you guys normally handle this type of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be separating your content from your codebase.

One strategy is storing your content at the deployment endpoint (on the server, where it will build over time as your application is used) and having capistrano symlink to it during a deployment.

Let's say you have a folder called 'uploads' located in '{rails_root}/public' -- you'd add something like this to your deployment recipe:

```
# Create a symlink to our 'uploads' folder
namespace :deploy do
  task :symlink_uploads, :roles => :app do
    run "ln -s #{deploy_to}/shared/uploads #{release_path}/public/uploads"
  end
end
after "deploy:update_code", "deploy:symlink_uploads"
```